# Adding multiple markers in Google Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have successfully managed to show the google map api v2. I want to add markers for my positions on it.

As per the documentation, I am only able to add one marker at a time or have to use a loop to add multiple.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo_v2);


        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ROMA).title("Hello").snippet("Nice Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
}
```

My question is, if I have a set of 10 LatLon values and the custom images, how can i show the multiple markers in API v2.

Thanks

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2

Comment: you can add multiple marker?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.size(); i++) {
    double lati=Double.parseDouble(pins.get(i).latitude);
    double longLat=Double.parseDouble(pins.get(i).longitude);
    MAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
       new LatLng(lati,longLat))
                  .title(pins.get(i)
                  .pinname)
                  .snippet(pins.get(i).address));
}
```

Comment: Could you please reformat your answer and add a small explanation?

Comment: what is pins? can you please explain me.

Comment: pins is your ArrayList, your Model- @BabulPatel

Comment: Its a bad idea not to add explanation for your code

Comment: where the ins came from?!