# Multiple marker in Map not showing with SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple markers in GoogleMaps. I am using Google SupportMapFragment. 
Onload my Map should show multiple markers based on data in arraylist however it shows only one marker.
I have researched on this and i saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846607/google-maps-v2-not-showing-multiple-markers) on  SO but i do not why there is only one marker showing on map.

Update i debugged my code and realized that in this line

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
```

only one position is getting passed before this line all data was being passed

Here is my code for same

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
       // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(19.2372, 72.8441);
        for(int i=0;i<providers.size();i++){
            NearbyDataProvider provider = providers.get(i);
            LatLng position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(provider.getLattitude())
                    ,Double.parseDouble(provider.getLongitude()));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
        }

    }
```

NearByDataProvider.class

> public class NearbyDataProvider {
>       int image;
>       String place;
>       String lattitude;
>       String longitude;
>
> ```
> public NearbyDataProvider(int image, String place, String lattitude, String longitude) {
>    this.setImage(image);
>    this.setPlace(place);
>    this.setLattitude(lattitude);
>    this.setLongitude(longitude);
> }
>
> public int getImage() {
>     return image;
> }
>
> public void setImage(int image) {
>     this.image = image;
> }
>
> public String getPlace() {
>     return place;
> }
>
> public void setPlace(String place) {
>     this.place = place;
> }
>
> public String getLattitude() {
>     return lattitude;
> }
>
> public void setLattitude(String lattitude) {
>     this.lattitude = lattitude;
> }
>
> public String getLongitude() {
>     return longitude;
> }
>
> public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
>     this.longitude = longitude;
> } }
> ```

LatLong to be passed

```
private String[] latitude = {"19.2372","19.1998","19.1802","19.1551","19.1405"};
    private String[] longitude = {"72.8441","72.8426","72.8554","72.8679","72.8422"};
```

Comment: Can you post the data of of the providers list?

Comment: sure @SushobhNadiger just a moment

Comment: yes , seems like your provider list has 1 item or less

Comment: @SushobhNadiger please see i have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

check this,

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> markersArray = new ArrayList<MarkerData>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < markersArray.size() ; i++) {

createMarker(markersArray.get(i).getLatitude(), markersArray.get(i).getLongitude(), markersArray.get(i).getTitle(), 
markersArray.get(i).getSnippet(), markersArray.get(i).getIconResID());
}


private void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {

 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(snippet));
}
```

Comment: I have seen this answer on SO from another thread what should i pass for iconResID @hasan_shaikh

Comment: iconResId mean your drawable icon for marker if you have. R.drawable.marker

Comment: but i'm using map.addMarker for marker and noth drawable so what should i do

Comment: I have updated the answer without a drawable marker. Check now