# Android: Adjust zoom to contain all marker

Tags: android, zooming, marker

Hi i've the following code:

```
PolylineOptions myPolyline =new PolylineOptions();

go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
...
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start));
myPolyline.add(start);

myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
myPolyline.add(destination);
fixZoom();
...
}

private void fixZoom() {
  List<LatLng> points = myPolyline.getPoints();
  LatLngBounds.Builder bc = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

  for (LatLng item : points) {
     bc.include(item);
  }

  myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bc.build(), 50));}
```

If i've one of my markers *OUT* of my current screen, this code work fine but, when i've already all my markers in the current camera screen, zoom level wont change while I would like to see it changed to the minimum possible (zoom IN so).

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set zoom to a latlngbound, you have to set a zize to the map.

Look this example!

[How to show multiple markers on MapFragment in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2)