# Adding multiple markers on Google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi I am developing small android application in which I want to display map and some markers on map. I have list of latlang values and i want to display it on map. I tried this in following way :

```
for(int pin=0; pin<pins.size(); pin++)
            {
                LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).latitude), Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).longitude));
                Marker storeMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(pinLocation)
                .title(pins.get(pin).pinname)
                .snippet(pins.get(pin).address)
                );
            }
```

So my problem is that when I try above method it just display last marker not showing all marker. How to do this. Need help. thank you.

Comment: Refer this one maybe useful ...http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/

Comment: Please follow the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int pin=0; pin<pins.size(); pin++)
{
        LatLng pinLocation = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).latitude), Float.parseFloat(pins.get(pin).longitude));
        Marker storeMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(pinLocation )-->here i had made some changes add "pinLocation" instead of "storeLocation"
        .title(pins.get(pin).pinname)
        .snippet(pins.get(pin).address)
        );
}
```

and after first check size of pins.size() ..

Comment: Altaf I tried your solution but still it is not working. Is there any other way

Comment: did you check your array size ??

Comment: yeah sir and size of array is 2. Still I don't know y it is showing me only last marker.

Comment: @nilkash I have exactly the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pins.size(); i++) {

 double lati=Double.parseDouble(pins.get(i).latitude);
 double longLat=Double.parseDouble(pins.get(i).longitude);
 MAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
 position(
 new LatLng(lati,longLat)).title(pins.get(i).pinname).snippet(pins.get(i).address));


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences like below

```
  // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

        // Getting number of locations already stored
        locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);

        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

        // If locations are already saved
        if(locationCount!=0){

            String lat = "";
            String lng = "";

            // Iterating through all the locations stored
            for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

                // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
                lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat"+i,"0");

                // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
                lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng"+i,"0");

                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));
            }
```

For marking Marker:

```
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

            // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
            editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

            // Storing the count of locations or marker count
            editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

            /** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
            editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));

            /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[Refer this one...source code is availbale](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ComponentMapList.size(); i++) {
                    String city = ComponentMapList.get(i).getCity();
                    if (city != null) {
                        center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                                ComponentMapList.get(i).getLat(),
                                ComponentMapList.get(i).getLng()));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                                new LatLng(ComponentMapList.get(i).getLat(),
                                        ComponentMapList.get(i).getLng()))
                                .title(city));
                    }
                }
```