# How to generate this kind of makers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

This is the Markers with labels

[image]

I want to generate this kind of markers.

I know how to generate markers but the trouble is with the labels.

I'm trying to do a wardriving that show the Acces Points in google maps

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [customize the icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker) of each marker.

Then put your image and write the text on the bitmap by code, and then set as the custom-marker with the `fromBitmap (Bitmap image)` method.

You can read this to :

[android Maps API v2 with custom markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers)

[How to show multiple markers on MapFragment in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2)