# Unable to add multiple markers in a Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to have a simpler implementation of Google Map in my Android App. I am able to launch Google Map but I am unable to show multiple markers there. If I keep the latitude and longitude values and name of the places hardcoded then things work, but dynamically with variables and String values I am unable to show them.
I have also gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2) suggested by many over here. But what I actually want is a simpler implementation of it.

Below is the code that I have used in my Main Activity:

```
public class Map_Activity_With_Fragment extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
String Origin, Destination, Start_Date, Num_Adult, Num_Infant, Origin_Map, Destination_Map;
Context context;
List<Address> Addr_Origin, Addr_Dest;
double latitude_origin, longitude_origin, latitude_destination, longitude_destination;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Origin = extras.getString(MainActivity.ORIGIN);
    Destination = extras.getString(MainActivity.DESTINATION);
    Start_Date = extras.getString(MainActivity.START_DATE);
    Num_Adult = extras.getString(MainActivity.ADULT);
    Num_Infant = extras.getString(MainActivity.INFANT);
    Origin_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.ORIGIN_MAP);
    Destination_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.DESTINATION_MAP);
    context = Map_Activity_With_Fragment.this;
    setTitle("Location Map");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map__with__fragment);

    try
    {
        initializeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map__with__fragment, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    AddMarkers(googleMap);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}

private void initializeMap()
{
    if (googleMap == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

private void AddMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        Addr_Origin = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Origin_Map, 1);
        Addr_Dest = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Destination_Map, 1);
        if (Addr_Origin.size() > 0) {
            latitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        if (Addr_Dest.size() > 0) {
            latitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin)).title(Origin_Map));
        Marker m2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_destination, longitude_destination)).title(Destination_Map));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Please help me out!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I am going to update my own question.

I was testing these code changes on a device of API level 16, and hence the markers and polylines were not getting rendered correctly. Then I tested this same code on a device of API level 19, and it worked perfectly fine. I did not modify any part of code for this. Things are working now. :)