# Is it possible to save Google Maps API markers using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps-api-3, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app that uses Google Maps.
I need to have the markers that users be created be saved onto a database, and I was wondering if I can use Firebase to save and bring back the markers.

If I can, can I also save pictures with the markers' coordinates? Thanks.

Comment: yes but the thing is that you have to save the lat lng not the marker in firebase database

Comment: But if I can save the lat lng, can I have it so that google maps places markers based on the saved lat lng?

Comment: yes you can put the marker on map

Comment: You need to store your LatLag in one arrayList and use for loop to add multiple markers.

Comment: How do I store the arrayList to Firebase?@ShubhankGupta

Comment: no need to store that at array

Comment: you retrive the data from json format store that in array

Comment: And from there, do the loop to place the markers?

Comment: yes follow the link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855049/how-to-show-multiple-markers-on-mapfragment-in-google-map-api-v2

Comment: if you still get the problem let me know. I try to code the complete example

Comment: Ok @Mozy give me some time i post the complete code with firebase and google map today.

Comment: @ShubhankGupta are you gonna post it here?

Comment: sorry for the delay. Today i definitely going to share. I am busy with one project thats why i am late to post sorry.. for that hope u understand. but today i surly post that

Comment: Oh no worries take your time @ShubhankGupta

Comment: @NoMoreStackOverflow Hey sorry if I am rushing, but I could really need the help